# SQL and foreign keys: How to link these two tables correctly?

Tags: sql, firebird

I am creating a Delphi application for my university and I'm stuck now. The program is about databases, and I use FireBird 2.1 as a database server. My database and application is about Linux distributions.

I am trying to link two tables in my Firebird database. The first table gives information about Distributions, and the second one gives information about Desktop Environments. There are two fields I want to link: Default Desktop Environment in the Distributions table and Desktop Environment Name in the DEs table.

One distribution can only have one default desktop environment, the one which is on the installation disc (or was chosen by the user during the installation). In the DEs table, there is a unique field, described DE's Name, so it should be linked to the Default DE field of Distributions.

But, one DE can be used as a default DE by **more than one** distribution, and this is where the conflict lies: Default DE field in the distros table has to be unique, but it's not. The thing I'm trying to reach is the referential integrity: Make the DEs table dependent.

Also, I've tried to create a third table which only consists of the DISTR_NAME and ENV_NAME fields, but the only thing I've reached with this one is to make this third table dependent on DISTROS and DES tables, but it's wrong. DES table should be dependent on DISTROS table, and I don't know how to do that. So any help would be appreciated! How to link these two tables correctly?

So I've created these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE DISTROS (
    DISTR_NAME  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ARCHITECT   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    DEFAULT_DE  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    LASTSTABLE  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PACKMANAGE  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE DES (
    ENV_NAME    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    USED_LANG   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    LASTSTABLE  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    SUPPORT_3D  SMALLINT,
    FILEMANAGE  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE DES ADD CONSTRAINT PK_DES PRIMARY KEY (ENV_NAME);
ALTER TABLE DES 
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DES_1 FOREIGN KEY (ENV_NAME) REFERENCES DISTROS (DE);
```

I can't figure out how to fix this problem: the distributions table must be parent table, and the DEs table must be child table. The distributions table should have primary key (DISTR_NAME field), and the DEs table should have foreign key (ENV_NAME field, linked with DE field of the distributions table).

But I can't do that, because SQL demands DE field of the distributions table to be the primary key. And the primary key has to be unique. However, one desktop environment can be used by many linux distributions, so this field can't possibly be unique. And I just can't figure out how to link these two tables correctly.

Comment: I removed the Delphi and IBExpert tags, as this question has absolutely nothing to do with the programming language or database management software being used. This is strictly a Firebird SQL question.

Comment: I think your foreign key should be from `DISTROS` to `DES` and not the other way around.

Comment: Mark Rotteveel, Yes! YES! Thank you VERY MUCH! Thank you! It helped and now everything works properly! Thank you!

Comment: @ArchAlessus I added an answer that builds on my comment, please accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you describe it, a *distribution* has a default *desktop environment*. This implies a foreign key from `DISTROS` to `DES`, but instead you model a foreign key the other way around. The destination of a foreign key requires a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`, hence the problem with your current solution.

The solution is to remove the foreign key from `DES` to `DISTROS` and replace it with:

```
ALTER TABLE DISTROS 
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DISTROS_DES FOREIGN KEY (DE) REFERENCES DES (ENV_NAME);
```

I would advise to re-study SQL and relational modelling, because these are the basics that you really need to know when working with SQL and (relational) databases.

Also, I know the 31 character limit for identifiers in Firebird can be a problem, but you should really try to use longer, descriptive, names (especially for `DES` and `DE`).

Comment: Thanks again. My knowledge of SQL is awful, but that's because I've only learned it in University 3 years ago, but not on my own. And the only thing I need this knowledge for is this work I've just finished. In future, if it will appear that I need to know SQL to do something, I will follow your advice and re-study it, but I don't need it now.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing sounds like a Many-to-Many relationship. Also it sounds like you almost are there on your own. There is always a 3rd table in M2M relationsihps as you described. Your final structure would look something like this.

```
**DISTROS**
DISTR_NAME - PK/Unique

**DISTROS_TO_DES** (PK contains both fields which are collectively unique)
DISTR_NAME FK to Distros.DISTR_NAME 
ENV_NAME  FK to DES.ENV_NAME

**DES**
ENV_NAME  - PK/Unique
```

One more bit of advice. You really don't want primary key values that are likely to change frequently, and consequently varchar fields are often a poor choice. I'd suggest adding an Auto-Incrementing (or identity) ID field to the DES and DISTROS tables for use as a PK.

Comment: It appears that I have to be more specific. In fact, to ease my work I made this DE field something like "Default DE" field... For example, default DE in OpenSUSE is KDE, and so on. So it's more like One-to-Many. And there is a problem: DES table should be dependent on the distributions table, but if I use this structure (as I mentioned earlier, I already have a similar one), the DEs table is not dependent, DISTROS_TO_DES table depends on it, but not vice-versa. And I don't know how to do this...

Comment: I suggest editing your question to be more clear. It is extremely hard to wade through to get to your actual question. Explain what you are trying to do in English instead of trying to translate it into your table structure.

Comment: I've edited my question and provided the additional information I've previously posted in my comment there. It seems I've described everything I could think of there. If it is still unclear, please tell me what information you need to make the question totally clear and I'll tell you that.